# Twilio - connect two active calls, via API, without using conference or enqueue

Tags: express, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have two active calls:

1. Incoming, interacting in an IVR app
2. Outgoing, interacting in an IVR app

I want to be able to tell the api to connect the two of them.

Option A - I can do it with a conference room, but then I'm paying extra fees for the room when I only need 2 participants.

Option B - I can do it by enqueueing call #1, then having call #2 dial the queue. But this seem impercise, and there is some extra complication when dealing with the queue.

Is there an Option C where I can call the API and direct it to connect the two calls?

Comment: Also, think of conference as a network media resource, as documented here - https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/contact-center-blueprint/call-control-concepts. It allows for additional call control which is what you are attempting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I know, those are the only two options for connecting two live calls. If you really want to avoid the conference call, then option B is your best bet.

Comment: OK, thanks. Is there a way to target a specific call within the queue, or I can only access the first one on the list?

Comment: You can't target a call in the queue, however, if you already know the two calls you could use the CallSid of one of the calls as the name for the queue. That way, the other call will know which queue to dial and that queue will only have one call in it.